# can't POST to github v3 API

Tags: javascript, json, github, gist

I'm trying to create a public gist via javascript. I'm not using any authentication - this is all client-side.

```
var gist = {
    "description": "test",
    "public": true,
    "files": {
        "test.txt": {
            "content": "contents"
        }
    }
};

$.post('https://api.github.com/gists', gist, function(data) {
});
```

The above code throws a 400: Bad Request - Problems parsing JSON. However, my JSON is valid. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing this from a website. There are possible cross site issues.

Comment: Probably should have said browser, not website.

Comment: A bit like http://groups.google.com/group/helma/browse_thread/thread/3a89ec84a2815338, did you check the encoding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aha - I can't pass an object to $.post. It needs to be stringified first:

```
var gist = {
    "description": "test",
    "public": true,
    "files": {
        "test.txt": {
            "content": "contents"
        }
    }
};

$.post('https://api.github.com/gists', JSON.stringify(gist), function(data) {});
```